# software like powerpoint that allows to present slide shows but also allows to change thickness of ink pen while in slide show mode

Tags: educational, powerpoint, slideshow

I am planning on using Power Point to create educational (mathematics) videos and use Power Point's Ink Pen functionality where needed to solve math problems.  I have a Wacom Tablet that allows me to solve math problems naturally (as I do with pencil and paper) and have them show up digitally on the power point slide, which is really cool.

The problem is, the ink thickness *while in slide show mode* cannot be adjusted in MS Power Point.  So I am wondering if there is other software out there like PowerPoint but will allow me to change thickness.

Also, I don't want to lose functionality like animations that PowerPoint does very well.  I use this so that students don't get information overload when presenting slides.

Comment: What about [LibreOffice Impress](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress) It is a presentation software,t hough I'm unsire it has any ink functionality.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - thanks for the comment.  yes, LibreOffice does not appear to have ink functionality.